# PS3 Final Fantasy XIV: Realm Reborn USED.?

Tags: ps3, final-fantasy-14

I'm looking to buy a used copy of. FF XIV: Realm Reborn for ps3 but I wanted to know if the game would play or not. I've heard that used MMO games for PC are a very bad idea but is that rule the same for the ps3? I will buy it new if I have to but if I can save a little money buying a used version I would. Would I have to buy some sort of access code or pass key?

Answer (score 4):

Like many MMOs, physical copies of Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn include a product key which must be registered to your Square Enix account. If a PS3 copy of the game has been previously opened, it's extremely likely that the product key has already been registered, rendering it useless to everyone but the original owner.

If you want to buy a copy of the game to play it, make sure that you either buy a new-and-sealed physical copy, or a digital download copy.

Comment: So could I buy a used copy and later buy a new product key?

Comment: Do not buy a used copy, it won't allow you to play the game. I don't believe that it's possible just to buy a "product key" without also buying a new full copy of the game (physical or digital).

Comment: Buying a new product key is equivalent to buying a new copy of the game. There is no difference. You can ask the retailer to just email you the product key to save on shipping, but the price will be the same otherwise. So there is no point insisting on getting  a used copy beforehand.